# Can I make springfox be package-aware?

Tags: spring, swagger-2.0, springfox

Let's say I have following classes

```
.../RabbitController
.../test/SomeController
```

springfox, without any swagger annotations, works fine.

```
rabbit-controller
some-controller
```

When I add another class

```
.../RabbitController
.../test/SomeController
.../test/RabbitController
```

An error comes out,

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'rabbitController'
for bean class [...RabbitController]
conflicts with existing,
non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
[.....test.RabbitController]
```

Is there any way to make springfox be aware of the hierarchy of the class so that I get something like

```
rabbit-controller
test-some-controller
test-rabbit-controller
```

?

Answer (score 1):

### Spring

- Spring will complain if you have two controllers of the same name. Spring names an autodetected component such as a bean marked with `@RestController` as an `uncapitalized non-qualified class name` in the absence of a `name` value.
- You can avoid the following error by naming the second `RabbitController` as `@RestController("test-rabbit-controller")`. You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator).

`Annotation-specified bean name 'rabbitController'
for bean class [...RabbitController]
conflicts with existing,
non-compatible bean definition of same name and class
[.....test.RabbitController]`

### Springfox

From the perspective of Springfox, you can make both the controllers distinct by having distinct `description` value in the `@Api` annotation.

Here are the changes you need to make:

### Controller 1

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@Api(description = "rabbit-controller",
        produces = "application/json", tags = {"1"})
public class RabbitController {
    ...
}
```

### Controller 2

```
@RestController("test-rabbit-controller")
@Slf4j
@Api(description = "test-rabbit-controller",
        produces = "application/json", tags = {"2"})
public class RabbitController {
    ...
}
```

[image]